# Creating a loop macro for excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a loop macro to save time during a project at work.

What I need to do is copy a number in column A in sheet 1 and then find the number in column A of sheet 2 (these are separate sheets on the same document) after this I need to copy the text in column C of the corresponding row and then paste this in column C in sheet 1.

Sorry this probably doesn't make much sense...

I don't have much experience using VBA so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My understanding: You want to look up a cell from column A in sheet 1 (A1) in column A of sheet 2, and want to return the corresponding cell in column C (CX) into column C of sheet 1?

Comment: Yeah that's right. I have 100's to do and I don't really want to spend hours doing a massive copy and paste job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need VBA for this. If you want to do what I think you want to do, use

```
=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A1, Sheet2!A:C, 3)
```

Put that into C1 (of Sheet 1), then copy it down.

[Documentation for VLOOKUP here.](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) Basically, (Sheet1!A1) is what you're looking for (Sheet2!A:C) is where you're looking for it, and (3) is the column in the range A:C (column C) that you're getting the information from. If for some reason you have data in columns B or C that match your data in A (making VLOOKUP useless), you want to use:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!A:A,0))
```

instead, which only searches through a single column.

[Tips for INDEX MATCH here.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214142)

Comment: Seems to be working thanks, although some are coming up as #N/A, but when I check the the number in column A in sheet 1 in sheet 2 there is a match? This would be a lot easier with pictures :(.

Comment: Do you have sample data? I'd be glad to help I just need to see what's throwing those errors.

Comment: I've taken out all confidential data so can send it across?

Comment: If you haven't figured it out yet, definitely send it. Make sure to get rid of anything confidential!

Comment: Actually I figured it out, I had some of the numbers in column A in sheet one stored as text. Thanks for all your help!!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for a `VLOOKUP`

Say your data on `Sheet1` looks like this:

```
+-------+--------+-------+
| Col A | Col. B | Col C |
+-------+--------+-------+
|   1   |        |       |
+-------+--------+-------+
|   2   |        |       |
+-------+--------+-------+
|   3   |        |       |
+-------+--------+-------+
```

You want to look up the values 1, 2, 3, etc. in `Sheet2` which may look something like this:

```
+-------+--------+-------+
| Col A | Col. B | Col C |
+-------+--------+-------+
|   1   |        |   A   |
+-------+--------+-------+
|   2   |        |   B   |
+-------+--------+-------+
|   3   |        |   C   |
+-------+--------+-------+
```

If I understand your question correctly, you want to look up the value in column A on `Sheet1` and return the corresponding match from `Sheet2` column C into column C of `Sheet1`.

In column C of `Sheet1` add the `VLOOKUP` formula, which looks like:

`=VLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, [range_lookup])`

The *lookup_value* is what you are looking for, in this case the value from `Sheet1` column A.

The *table_array* are the cells you want to look at to find the lookup_value in.  When using this lookup, the left-most column in this table_array is used as the column to match on.  In this case it is `'Sheet2'!A1:C3`

The *col_index_num* is the corresponding column you want to return if a match is found.  In this case it is column 3.

Finally, the *[range_lookup]* should be set to `FALSE` if you want an exact match only or `TRUE` if you want to return the first approximate match.

So in this case we want to add the `VLOOKUP` formula to the first row in column C of `Sheet1` as such:

```
+-------+--------+-----------------------------------------+
| Col A | Col. B |                  Col C                  |
+-------+--------+-----------------------------------------+
|   1   |        | =VLOOKUP(A2,'Sheet2'!$A$1:$C$3,3,FALSE) |
+-------+--------+-----------------------------------------+
|   2   |        |                                         |
+-------+--------+-----------------------------------------+
|   3   |        |                                         |
+-------+--------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Press enter to get the results.  Drag the formula down the rest of the column.

A couple of notes:

- If no match in Column C of `Sheet2` is found, the function returns a `#N/A` error, you can handle that by using the `IFERROR` function
- VLOOKUP returns only the first match in Column C of `Sheet2`, if there are multiple matches you will need to consider adjusting the lookup so that it is specific enough such that each lookup has only one corresponding value

You can read about the VLOOKUP function on [MSDN](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) and view some tutorials [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13780/using-vlookup-in-excel/).  Specifically the common problems and best practices sections of the MSDN article.

Answer (score 0):

agree with kfitcher, vba isn't needed. alternative to vlookup is index/match as follows

`=INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!A:A,0))`